# MySQL workbench config is corrupted in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-workbench

This isn't a programming question, per se, so if this is in the wrong area, please tell me where I should put it and I'll see what I can do to get it moved.

I am working on a Java project which uses MySQL database.  My system is Ubuntu 15.04.  I have installed Java, Eclipse and MySQL with no issues (that I have encountered).  I installed MySQL Workbench with little difficulty.  I created a "localhost" connection which seemed to be working fine.  I started attempting to run the scripts which were supposed to set up my database appropriately to emulate the client's database setup.  I'm new to MySQL and Workbench, so there were some issues.  I finally worked through the bulk of the issues but I didn't have a connection at the end of it all.  So I closed that connection tab and tried to open a new connection.  My "localhost" connection didn't show up, so I went to manage connections to see why it didn't show and there were no saved connections listed.  As soon as I clicked on the "New" button, I got a "Home Screen Error" indicating that Workbench "Could not save XML data to file */home/username/.mysql/workbench/other_connections.xml*

I had to sudo in a terminal window just get into the directory - and everything in that directory is owned by root with the XML files readable by others.  I have gone through all of the "suggestions" I can find online on how to clean up stuff - most having to do with apt-get.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled MySQL Workbench through the Ubuntu Software Center.  Nothing makes a difference.  I would appreciate any help I can get.  Thank you.

Comment: Strange. The base path should be "/home/yourusername/.mysql/workbench/" and not simply "/home//.mysql/workbench/" -- not sure how your username would be missing from the path. An Ubuntu build system error? Not sure why or how this happened, but this feels like the reason. Related, consider using the official [MySQL APT repo](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/).

Comment: You are correct, I cut my username out of that string and failed to replace it.  Editing the post.  Actually, I had replaced my user name with "username" in angle brackets, which didn't display in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolved.  The permissions on the .mysql/ directory were truly messed up - the directory belonged to *root* rather than my username, but it wasn't the Linux root account, rather the root account from the MySQL database - because I did some rather unintelligent things in an effort to get up and running quickly.  Removing MySQL and reinstalling didn't work.

The solution ended up with a clean install of the OS (it was a recent install, anyway), install MySQL on the clean OS and IMMEDIATELY creating a user account with my Linux username (not sure if that's required, but it's what I did).  I had no further issues with this after that.  I realize that this may not be **THE** answer for everybody, but it's what I did and it worked.

Comment: I did `chown $USER -R ~/.mysql` and this fixed the issue, this recursively changes the ownership of a folder to the current logged user, fixing the problem. Didn't need a complete reinstall of the OS